# Angular Firebase Getting Zoneaware with Promisses

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, promise

I don't understand why I'm getting a Zoneaware with this code. Can anybody help me?

Here is the rational:
Step 1 get the data as an array and then map it and call step 2.
Step 2 get the ID executorID from the step1 and return an object.
Step 3 get the users data and return an object. Please ignore the ELSE, that's for something else.

So the idea is that in the end I get a complete object.

```
// Step 1 get the data as an array and then map it and call step 2.
getPanic(checkID: string) {
    return this.db.firestore.collection(`${this.PATH}`).where('checkId', '==', checkID).get()
        .then(data => {
            return data.docs.map(async d => {
                const panicObj = {id: d.id, ...d.data() } as any;
                panicObj.actions = await this.getActions(panicObj.id);
                return panicObj;
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

// Step 2 get the ID executorID from the step1 and return an object,
getActions(panicID: string) {
    return this.db.firestore.collection(`${this.PATH}${panicID}/actions`).get()
            .then(data => {
                return data.docs.map(async d => {
                    const actionObj = d.data();
                    actionObj.executorData = await this.userService.getUser(actionObj.executor, true);
                    return actionObj;
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

// Step 3 get the users data and return an object. Please ignore the ELSE, that's for something else.
getUser(uid, asPromise?: boolean) {
    if (asPromise) {
        return this.db.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).get()
                .then(uData => {
                    return uData.data();
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    return err;
                });
    } else {
        return this.db.doc<Interviewers>(`users/${uid}`).valueChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chellappanவ thanks but this is unrelated to the question.

Comment: As per firesbase documentation if you want to query you have to pass query function as second argument to collection method. But in your example your are chaining methods

Comment: The issue is not the query. The data is coming perfectly. The issue is that I get the Zoneaware which nests the data within its own object.

Comment: Then it might be some other issue.